# cannot convert between an Identity Class and a local one in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently developing with ASP.NET MVC and after I have created the an error of converting a local class to an Identity one `cannot implicitly convert "ListUsers" to "Identity.IdentityUser"`(I simplified the error a bit) anyway, here are some bits of code:
ListUsersController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ServiceReferenceAuthentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using SoftSMS.Data.Data;
using SoftSMS.Data.Entities;
using SoftSMS.Data.Entity;
using SoftSMS.Data.Interfaces;
using SoftSMS.MVC.ViewModels;

namespace SoftSMS.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class ListUsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ListUsers> userManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork<ListUsers> _users;

        //private readonly DataContext _context;

        public ListUsersController(IUnitOfWork<ListUsers> Users/*DataContext context*/)
        {
            _users = Users;
            //_context = context;
        }

        // GET: ListUsers
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_users.Entity.GetAll());
        }

        // GET: ListUsers/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAsync(Guid? id)
        {
            
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ...
            if (listUsers == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(listUsers);
        }

        // GET: ListUsers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ListUsers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,UserName,FirstName,LastName,Status,Profil")] ListUsers listUsers)
        {
            try
            {
                TPFAuthenticationSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new TPFAuthenticationSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration();
                TPFAuthenticationSoapClient servAuth = new TPFAuthenticationSoapClient(endpointConfiguration);
                if ((Boolean)TempData["isValid"] == false)
                {
                    IdentityUser u = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(listUsers.UserName);

                    if (u != null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.IsValid = false;
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Ce Compte existe déja");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        ...;


                        if (x != null)
                        {
                            ...
                            


                            return View(listUsers);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ...

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ...
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                return View(listUsers);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }
        }
```

the error is in `IdentityUser u = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(listUsers.UserName);`
I don't want to create an operator override as it's suggested (nor explicit conversion),
ListUsers.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using SoftSMS.Data.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace SoftSMS.Data.Entity
{  public enum StatusType
    { Banned,Registered,Normal,Warned}
    public enum ProfilType
    { Admin,Manager,Agent}
    public class ListUsers : IdentityUser
    { 
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        public StatusType Status { get; set; }
        public ProfilType Profil { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<MembershipAssociations> MembershipAssociation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Template> TemplateNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SentMsg> SentmsgNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UsersViewModel.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SoftSMS.MVC.ViewModels
{  public enum StatusType
    { Banned,Registered,Normal,Warned}
    public enum ProfilType
    { Admin,Manager,Agent}
    public class UsersViewModel : IdentityUser
    { 
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public StatusType Status { get; set; }
        public ProfilType Profil { get; set; }
        public List<MembershipAssociationViewModel> MembershipAssociation { get; set; }
        public List<SentMsgViewModel> Sentmsg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and Create.cshtml:

```
@model SoftSMS.MVC.ViewModels.UsersViewModel

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Create"; }
@{TempData["isValid"] = ViewBag.isValid;}

<br />
<h3>Nouvel Utilisateur</h3>
<hr />
@*@ViewBag.Result1*@
<br />
<h4 style="color: red;">@TempData["errorMessage"]</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>


            @if ((Boolean)ViewBag.isValid == false)
            {
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label">Login</label>
    <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>            }

            @if ((Boolean)ViewBag.isValid == true)
            {
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label">Login</label>
                    <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label">Prenom</label>
                                    <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstName)
                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label">Nom</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
                                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastName)
                                                </div>
                                                               
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                                                                                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
                                                                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                    <label asp-for="EstActif" class="control-label">Actif</label>
                                                                                                    <select id="Select1" asp-for="EstActif" class="form-control">
                                                                                                        <option value="True"> <text>OUI</text></option>
                                                                                                        <option value="False"> <text>NON</text></option>
                                                                                                    </select>
                                                                                                </div>            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Creer" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Liste des utilisateurs</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

as you could have seen, I had to make the UI in French (even though I don't like it) because I am developing this platform for French people,
if you need another resource, I could share it, but not the entire app, the `...`is for a confidential code,
thank you

Comment: BTW I added a property called `IsActive` in the ViewModel, in the class, in the controller and I modified `EstActif?` in the create.cshtml, in the controller it became `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,UserName,FirstName,LastName,IsActive")] ListUsers listUsers)` but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: I also added the Profil and ProfilType on the respected pages (Create.cshtml and controller)

Comment: I also corrected all the other issues except the above error